# How do I run gitbash as a terminal with a python file

Tags: python, git-bash

I installed both Python and GitBash. I was wondering how I could allow gitbash to become a terminal for  a python file I would like to run.

Thanks.

I am using Python 3.4 btw.

Comment: `how I could allow gitbash to become a terminal for a python file I would like to run` I think you need to explain what that's supposed to mean

Comment: Sorry. I mean that if I were to have some doctests on my python file, I would like gitbash to access my python file and act as a terminal running those doctests.

Comment: i cant remember in which order i installed them but i think it worked out of the box for me... so if you are on windows, try to restart and have a look at your path.

Comment: You can run Python from within `bash` the same way you do from within `cmd`. If it's on your `%PATH` in `cmd`, it's on your `$PATH` in `bash`, so you can just run `python`. If it's not on your `%PATH%` and you have to instead type a full path in `cmd`, you have to do the same in `bash`.